# Show that a local coordiate formula defines a tensor of type (0,2)

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I've already shown that $w(X,Y) = \mathcal{L}_X(\lambda(Y)) - \mathcal{L}_Y(\lambda(X)) - \lambda([X,Y]) $ defines a tensor of type (0,2) by showing that it's multilinear and $C^{\infty}$-linear in every argument.
I've also shown that the formula of that tensor in local coordinates reads: $\partial_i \lambda_j - \partial_j \lambda _i$.

I now want to show, independent of the results above, that this local coordinate formula
$$w_{i_j} = \partial_i \lambda_j - \partial_j \lambda _i$$ defines a tensor of type (0,2). To do that, I need to show that this formula is coordinate invariant. But I'm not exactly sure, what is meant by that.

I think I have to show that $$ w_{i_j}X^iY^j = \tilde{\omega}_{i_j} \tilde{X}^i \tilde{Y}^j $$
where the symbold with tilde on top, should turn out to be as the transformation rule for tensors predicts.

But I'm a little confused. Do I have to plug in the transformation formulas $\partial_i = \frac{\partial \tilde{x}^k}{\partial x^i}\tilde{\partial}_k$ and $\lambda_j = \tilde{\lambda}_k \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial \tilde{x}^j}$ and $\tilde{X^i} = X^k \frac{\partial \tilde{x}^i}{\partial x^k} $ and check that these two expression are the same or am I completely going in the wrong direction?

Quick feedback would be nice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, that's what you have to do.